# Get AngularJS template bindings

Tags: angularjs

I am working on something like CMS based on AngularJS templates. I need to get bindings from a template so my users are able to fullfill those properties for specific pages.

So how can I get all bindings from a template?

Comment: The template should have a scope associated with it.  Do you mean how to get the scope associated with a binding?

Comment: I wanna make my user specify data that will be put in scope

Comment: You should bind to a model object (like $scope.bindings), then bind your view to it. That way, you can interrogate the bindings object for its properties. Those properties should represent your bindings.

Comment: Are you asking about getting the bind expressions out of a template so that you can dynamically add matching scope properties? I'm almost certain you'd have to use a regex to parse the template since I know of no method to do that with Angular.

Answer (score 1):

You can't... using techniques AngularJS itself provides. Your question is just beyond the scope of the functionality the core devs thought to provide.

@bmceldowney is correct - a regex could be used to parse templates, although I think that would be challenging for a few reasons:

- AngularJS templates can contain all sorts of complex expressions, not just simple vars. How will you deal with filters - and if you won't, you lose a lot of value here...
- AngularJS can lazy-load templates and this is a common practice. You wouldn't want hundreds of useless templates floating around just in case they might be used at some point. How will you deal with templates that haven't been loaded yet - that you don't know exist?

  - If you're building a CMS that implies data management of some kind, and that's not going to get stored in the front-end because it would be useless there - nobody else would ever see it. So aside from the editing cycle itself, it seems like something to be solved server-side and not with AngularJS.

All that said, my suggestion would be to do exactly that - work out something server-side where you can access templates as raw files just by scanning some folder where they're stored, use regular expressions to find the template variables, and you're going to have to be clever with how you parse expressions and what you'll support here. Then you can prepare appropriate data objects to pass down to the client via an API for it to support the actual editing.